# MYSQL Joins in Select query

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a database to manage a sport league table which needs a separate tabe to hold details of occasional points variations that fall outside the normal logic of the league table calculation.

The two tables I have are

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fixtures` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comp_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `hteam_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ateam_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hscore1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ascore1` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hscore2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ascore2` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hbonus` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `abonus` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `played` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pointsadjust` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fix_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `team_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

The query I am using to pull together the league table is

```
SELECT
  tname AS Team, Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
  SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(SD) AS SD,SUM(BP) AS BP,SUM(Pts)+SUM(BP) AS Pts, SUM(((Pts+BP)*10000)+(W*100)+(SD*10)+((F/P)*1)) AS Rank
FROM(
  SELECT
    hteam_id Team,
    1 P,
    IF(hscore1 > ascore1,1,0) W,
    IF(hscore1 = ascore1,1,0) D,
    IF(hscore1 < ascore1,1,0) L,
    hscore1 F,
    ascore1 A,
    hscore1-ascore1 SD,
    hbonus BP,
    CASE WHEN hscore1 > ascore1 THEN 2 WHEN hscore1 = ascore1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
  FROM fixtures WHERE comp_id = '1' AND played = 'N'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    ateam_id,
    1,
    IF(hscore1 < ascore1,1,0),
    IF(hscore1 = ascore1,1,0),
    IF(hscore1 > ascore1,1,0),
    ascore1,
    hscore1,
    ascore1-hscore1,
    abonus,
    CASE WHEN hscore1 < ascore1 THEN 2 WHEN hscore1 = ascore1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM fixtures WHERE comp_id = '1' AND played = 'N'
) as tot
JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

I am struggling to create the second join to bring in the data from the points adjust table to make the adjustments to the league table.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: you can warp it with one big select and then inner join it with another table

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to replace your block of code of the sub-query "tot" for this one, and point to the new column "Pts_Adjst" (witch holds the adjusted punctuation) instead of "Pts" (the "vanilla" punctuation):

SQL Fiddle (example): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7a3c/14

```
SELECT
#tname AS Team,
Team TeamiD,
Sum(P) AS P,Sum(W) AS W,Sum(D) AS D,Sum(L) AS L,
SUM(F) as F,SUM(A) AS A,SUM(SD) AS SD,SUM(BP) AS BP,SUM(Pts_Adjst)+SUM(BP) AS Pts, SUM(((Pts_Adjst+BP)*10000)+(W*100)+(SD*10)+((F/P)*1)) AS Rank
FROM(SELECT tot.*, CASE WHEN pointsadjust.value is not null THEN pointsadjust.value ELSE PTS END PTS_ADJST, pointsadjust.reason FROM (
SELECT
 hteam_id Team,
 id Fix,
 1 P,
 IF(hscore1 > ascore1,1,0) W,
 IF(hscore1 = ascore1,1,0) D,
 IF(hscore1 < ascore1,1,0) L,
 hscore1 F,
 ascore1 A,
 hscore1-ascore1 SD,
 hbonus BP,
 CASE WHEN hscore1 > ascore1 THEN 2 WHEN hscore1 = ascore1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PTS
FROM fixtures WHERE comp_id = '1' AND played = 'N'
UNION ALL
SELECT
 ateam_id,
 id Fix,
 1,
 IF(hscore1 < ascore1,1,0),
 IF(hscore1 = ascore1,1,0),
 IF(hscore1 > ascore1,1,0),
 ascore1,
 hscore1,
 ascore1-hscore1,
 abonus,
 CASE WHEN hscore1 < ascore1 THEN 2 WHEN hscore1 = ascore1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
 FROM fixtures WHERE comp_id = '1' AND played = 'N'
) as tot
LEFT JOIN pointsadjust 
ON tot.Team = pointsadjust.team_id AND tot.Fix = pointsadjust.Fix_id) as tot
#JOIN teams t ON tot.Team=t.id
GROUP BY Team
ORDER BY Rank DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The points adjustments occur on fixtures that are not played so in the fixtures table the field played is set 'N'.  If that is included in the SELECT then the fixture is not found with the join as the same id used in the points adjust table.  Can I exclude the match from the league table but recover the points adjustments from the pointsadjust table?